# Why does this code never switch back to the object at index 0?

Tags: c#

I have two `GameObject`s in an array, and the S key is used to cycle an index referring the objects in this array.

When I run the game for the first time and press S, it changes from 0 to 1 and then to 2. After that it just cycles between 1 and 2... but it should be changing between 0 and 1 only; there are only two objects.

Why is this behavior occurring? My code is below:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SwitchObjects : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] objects;
    public int activeIndex = 0;

    public void SetActiveObject(int aIndex)
    {
        activeIndex = aIndex;
        for (int i = 0; i < objects.Length; i++)
            objects[i].SetActive(i == activeIndex);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
        {
            if (activeIndex == objects.Length)
                activeIndex = 0;
            activeIndex++;
            SetActiveObject(activeIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I belive your problem is here:

```
        if (activeIndex == objects.Length)
            activeIndex = 0;
        activeIndex++;
```

You set activeIndex to zero, but then increment it immediately.
So the solution should be:

```
if (activeIndex == objects.Length)
    activeIndex = 0;
else
    activeIndex++;
```

Comment: your solution is working but I also needed to change this line: if (activeIndex == objects.Length - 1) Only if I'm adding -1 it's changing between the two indexs 0 and 1. Without it, it will keep changing between indexs 0 1 and 2 and I can't figure out what is index 2 if there are only two objects in the array.  So adding -1 make it acting like I wanted.

Comment: You get index 2 because it is the number of elements inside _objects_. And yes, you're right, completely forgot about -1.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (activeIndex == objects.Length)
                activeIndex = 0;
++activeIndex;
```

This statement resets activeIndex to 0 then immediately adds 1, so activeIndex can never be reset to 0.